# Javascript Class - undefined is not a function when calling function

Tags: javascript, class, oop, iife

I´m trying to program OO in javascript. There are several variants of doing this.

I have seen something I think in some AnglularJS examples which is for me the clearest one.

Sadly I´m getting

> undefined is not a function

when calling a function of my instance

```
var MyChooser = (function () {

    var self = this;
    var constructor = function (selectBox, previewBox) {
        this.selectBox = selectBox;
        this.previewBox = previewBox;
        this.selectBox.change(function () {
            alert(this.value);
        })
    };

    MyChooser.prototype.loadFrames = function () {
        alert("load");
        $.ajax({url: "api.php"}).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
            //self.frames = data;
        })
    };

    MyChooser.prototype.displayFrame = function (frame) {
        this.previewBox.setAttribute("src", frame.src);
    };

    MyChooser.prototype.invalidateSelectBox = function () {

    };

    return constructor;
});



 var fp = new MyChooser(document.getElementById("frame-select"), document.getElementById("frame-preview"));
            fp.loadFrames();
```

Why do I get this error?

(I also removed the jquery calls, but it is not the problem)

Comment: Why are you defining the constructor inside the "MyChooser constructor" instead of just modifying and returning the MyChooser instance?

Comment: I think youre missing the iife

Comment: @NicoSantangelo I have seen this in an example

Comment: @Sherman S what do you mean with iife?

Comment: Immediately invoked function. The end of mychooser after the return statement should be something like })(MyChooser || new MyChooser()); or something like that. I cant remember if thats what you put inside the extra () but its something like that

Comment: @ShermanS could that really be the point? I mean I´m already invoking the new operator from outside. Also I need to call the constructor to do my initializations. I have tried it with "MyChooser" as return statement, but nothing changed

Comment: @Nachbar90 you're using `new` to call that outer function, not the `constructor` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lack a `()` at the end to make the enclosing function an IIFE.

```
var MyChooser = (function () {

  var constructor = function(select,...stuff){...}

  // Note we're using constructor.prototype rather than MyChooser.prototype
  constructor.prototype.foo = function...
  ...

  return constructor;
}()); // Note the ()
```

Without it, your `constructor` won't be assigned/returned to `MyChooser`. You end up with `MyChooser` being a function that returns `constructor`, rather than `constructor` itself. Also, change your prototype methods to point to `constructor` instead of `MyChooser`.

Also, all this confusion reasulted from the fact that the constructor and it's method definitions are placed in a closure - which is not necessary. You can simply go with:

```
function MyChooser(select,...stuff){...}
MyChooser.prototype.moarStuff = function(){...};

...

var fp = new MyChooser(...);
```

Comment: This is all true, but the way the `.prototype` is set up will mean that it won't work that way either. The prototype assignments need to be made to `constructor.prototype`, not `MyChooser.prototype`.

Comment: thank you very much, now it works :)) I have also renamed constructor to MyChooser to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

This can work:

```
 var MyChooser = (function () {
    function MyChooser (p1, p2) {

    }

    MyChooser.prototype.f1 = function () {
        return true;
    };

    return MyChooser 
})();

var thisChooser = new MyChooser(param1, param2);
```

Notice the iife, im returning MyChooser instead of the constructor, and how the constructor is defined.

Comment: thank you for constructor -> MyChooser tip. makes it much more clearer

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you're doing OO in Javascript, let me introduce you to a better way of creating objects in javascript that is cleaner, easier to read, and *safer*. I learned it while reading the excellent book "Javascript: The Good Parts"

Here is how you can create your object.

```
var constructor = function (spec) {
    var that;

    var privateFunc = function () {};
    var privateVariables = ...;

    var publicMethod = function () {};

    that = Object.create({
        publicMethod: publicMethod,
        // public methods and properties
    });
    return that;
};
```

Now whenever you need an object, just do

```
var newObject = constructor();
```

This is much more flexible and cleaner IMHO. And it saves you from accidentally polluting global scope if you ever forget to type the `new` keyword.

Comment: The thing is, I wanted to have a class structure like in Java for example, as I´m used to it. It´s not so nice that everything is definded in the constructor.... But anyway I´ll try that.

Comment: You might have heard about factory pattern. It is quite extensively used in Java. This above constructor is an example of factory pattern. It might look a bit weird at first but it avoids a lot of bad practices and common mistakes. Do give the above mentioned book a read in your free time. It's worth it ;-)